# Windows 10 installer keeps restarting

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to do clean install of Win 10 32bit (CPU is not 64bit) on my DELL optiplex gx620 P4, 2GB RAM. Windows installer start up and after few seconds restarts PC without any error message. I have run integrated memory test without any error. PC is running with Win XP fine. 
Any tips?

Thnx!

Comment: Do you have more information? What says the installer while 'installing'?

Comment: nothing :( just windows logo and restart

Comment: What did you do so far? Did you boot the computer up from a DVD/Flashdrive to clean install Windows? Did you already press the buttons to start the install process? Did you already tried other options?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no chance to select anything. I have two possible install sources - flash drive with 64/32bit and dvd with 32bit installation. Only thing I am able to select is when I boot from flash drive where can I select 64bit (does not work because of cpu) or 32bit installation (win logo apears and after about 10sec. restart) or memory test.... it looks to me like it loads some prep files and when it tryes to run graphic installer it crashes...

Comment: Can you format the drive?

Comment: The drive is brand new. Installer is not so far to do that...

Comment: I am sorry... Then I don't know.

Comment: Thnx! Anyway I formated drive on another pc and still the same...

Answer (score 0):

I have tested everything and everything works fine and meets minimal requirements. Lucky me I have another CPU to try so I replaced original 
Intel® Pentium® 4 Processor 505/505J (1M Cache, 2.66 GHz, 533 MHz FSB) with P4 3.2GHz, 800MHz, 2M Cache and voila installer starts as usual...